# Display Two Forms in one Template in Django

Tags: python, django

My aim is to use Two models in One template. I have tried various ways around this and have had no success. Originally I had 2 views, 2 models and Two forms. After searching I found people using inlineformsets. So I dropped One of the Views and set-up the inlineformset. 
This is currently where I am up to and seem to be hitting a wall.

The template renders to the browser and the 'object_list' part displays the database content as desired and the 'form' part renders the form and validates/saves the data correctly. The issue is with the 'formset'. No fields are rendered (I would expect to see a dropdown as the field is a foreignkey) and when the 'submit' button is pressed I get:

```
AttributeError at /settings/

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Any help in finding the error or pointers on alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated.

### The Code:

#### models.py

```
from django.db import models

class RevisionSettings(models.Model):    
    global_revision_type = models.CharField(max_length = 5, unique=True, blank = True)
    global_revision_description = models.CharField(max_length = 300, unique=True, blank = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["global_revision_type"]

    def __unicode__(self):  
        return u'%s %s' % (self.global_revision_type, self.global_revision_description)


class RevisionDefaultType(models.Model):
    defaultrevisiontype = models.ForeignKey(RevisionSettings)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["defaultrevisiontype"]

    def __unicode__(self):  
        return unicode(self.defaultrevisiontype)
```

#### views.py

```
class RevisionSettingsView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'settings/revisionsettings_view.html'
    model = RevisionSettings
    form_class = SettingsForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('globalsettings')
    success_message = 'Successfully added your new revision type'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        formset = SettingsFormSet(instance = RevisionSettings)
    return self.render_to_response(
        self.get_context_data(form=form,
                              formset=formset))

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        formset = SettingsFormSet(self.request.POST)
        if 'rev_settings_form_1' in self.request.POST:
            if form.is_valid():
                return self.form_valid(form)
            else:
                return self.form_invalid(form)
        elif 'rev_settings_form_2' in self.request.POST:
            if formset.is_valid():
                return self.formset_valid(formset)
            else:
                return self.form_invalid(formset)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def formset_valid(self, formset):
        self.object.save()
        formset.instance = self.object
        formset.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def form_invalid(self, form, formset):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form,formset=formset))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['object_list'] = RevisionSettings.objects.order_by('global_revision_type')
        return super(RevisionSettingsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

#### forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory

from .models import RevisionSettings, RevisionDefaultType

class SettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = RevisionSettings

class DefaultSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = RevisionDefaultType

SettingsFormSet = inlineformset_factory(RevisionSettings, RevisionDefaultType)
```

#### revisionsettings_view.html

(I have removed most of the HTML styling to keep the information to the point)

```
{% extends 'base_private.html' %}

{% block content %}

    {% for object in object_list %}

        <tr>
            <td align="center">{{ object.global_revision_type }}</td>
            <td align="center">{{ object.global_revision_description }}</td>
            <td align="center"><a href="/settings/{{ object.id }}/delete" class="tooltip-test" title="" data-original-title="Delete selected revision type"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></a></td>
        </tr>

    {% endfor %}

    <form action = '{{ action }}' method = 'POST' class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                {{ formset.management_form }}
                {% for form in formset %}
                    {{ form.id }}
                    {{ form.defaultrevisiontype.label_tag }}
                    {{ form.defaultrevisiontype }}
                {% endfor %}
            </td>
        </tr>

        <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input type = 'submit' name = 'rev_settings_form_2' value = 'Update Default Revision Type' class = 'btn btn-success'>
        </span>

            <td align="center">{{ form.global_revision_type }}{{ form.global_revision_type.errors }}</td>
            <td align="center">{{ form.global_revision_description }}{{ form.global_revision_description.errors }}</td>
        </tr>

        <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input type = 'submit' name = 'rev_settings_form_1' value = 'Add Revision Type' class = 'btn btn-success'>
        </span>

    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I'm not a big fan of Generic CBV, why don't you write your view not inheriting from the CreateView, wouldn't make it easier?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I would but as im pretty new to Django, i dont know how. Im sure a search or Two can provide some answers.

Comment: Thinking about it, do you mean function based views instead of CBVs?

Comment: You can use CBV, but without the CreateView as base... you can inherit from View or TemplateView: http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.6/django.views.generic.base/View/
http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.6/django.views.generic.base/TemplateView/

This way you've more control over what your function do.
your case may be not well handled by the CreateView.

Comment: @danielfranca is correct, although you could also use CreateView to handle one of the forms, and handle the other in the `post` method. I think Daniel's solution is better, though. Checkout django-oscar's Login/Register view which displays two forms: [`AccountAuthView`](https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar/blob/master/oscar/apps/customer/views.py#L90)

Comment: Thanks guys. Ill give it a go now and let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 1):

Formsets are overkill for two forms. This is actually not too hard but poorly documented.  You can make both forms the same form type, just give a prefix.

```
def parent_apply(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    parent_form = SignupForm(request.POST, prefix="parent")
    student_form = StudentApplyForm(request.POST, prefix="student")
    if parent_form.is_valid() and student_form.is_valid():
      parent = parent_form.save()
      student = student_form.save(parent)
    else: messages.error(request, "Please correct the errors marked in red.")
  else:
    parent_form = SignupForm(prefix="parent")
    student_form = StudentApplyForm(prefix="student")

  return render_to_response('template_path/forms.html', { 'parent_form':parent_form, 'student_form':student_form }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The forms are just regular Django forms, no special settings required.  You can change the order on which they validate and save one even if the other did not validate if you choose.

In your HTML Template, wrap both forms in the same  tag and they will submit at the same time.  If you want your forms to go to different view functions, specify two different  elements.

Comment: can you add a sample of HTML for this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. The pointers really helped me come to this solution. The main change was to 'def get' as shown below. I dropped the formset and passed the forms this way.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     form = self.settings_form_class
     formset = self.default_form_class

     return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form = form, formset = formset))
```

I was unaware this was possible! Thanks again.